# How to connect two telegram bots between each other?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram bots and I wanted that one bot sends messages to a chat and another bot reads the messages, filters it and sends filtered messages to me.

I read related articles here, but I haven't found any appropriate solution.
I read that it isn't possible to create transfering messages between two bots because one can't see messages from another.
But still I haven't found final answer here.

Can you help me, is it possible or not?

And if it's possible, how to connect one bot to another?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that or rather you're not allowed to. Because it will create an infinite loop between both the bots.
To avoid that Telegram bot has some restrictions.
It can't reach to someone unless they have messaged the bot previously. So, theoretically it is impossible.